# criteria for percent error?

Tags: error

I have 2 arrays. The first array is system rating 
`{69.73, 56.93, 68.64, 65.58, 70.36, 67.44, 56.34, 75.03, 51.58, 65.7}`
 The second array is human rating `{64.8, 74.8, 87.6, 77.55, 71.95, 58.35, 62.55, 62.25, 66.2, 66.1}` 
I use the following percent error formula from http://www2.phy.ilstu.edu/~wenning/slh/Percent%20Difference%20Error.pdf

$\text{percentError} = |\text{AcceptedValue} - \text{Experiment}| / |\text{Accepted Value}| * 100$. The value 69.73 compared to 64.8, 56.93 compared to 74.8 and so on. Then, error values = 7.6, 23.8, 21.6, 15.4, 2.20, 15.57, 9.92, 20.5, 22.08, 0.605. And this error value if on average produces 13.95. I want to ask, what are the criteria for the error value? Is it bad, moderate or strong criteria?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer for a question like this. It will depend on the subject area. Even if we assume that "system rating" is correct (a gold standard) then there are fields where humans are very good at judging and fields where they are much worse.

You will have to think about your subject area and consider whether 13.95 is good or bad. You will also have to define "criteria" - criteria for what?

In some fields, there will be previous work and you will be able to compare your results to others.